# Castle Windsor: Registering all implementations of an interface having the same constructor parameter

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, castle

I have multiple implementations of the same interface who all have the same constructor parameter (strConn).  Is it possible to register all implementations with 1 container.Register call?

Here is what I have:

```
container.Register(
            Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<IUserMenuDao>()
                .BasedOn<IDataAccess>().WithService.FromInterface()
            );
```

These implementations all have the same constructor parameter; strConn.  Registering one would be:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IUserMenuDao>()
                               .DependsOn(new {strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABC123"].ConnectionString})
                               .ImplementedBy<UserMenuDaoSqlServerImpl>());
```

Is there a way to register by convention similar to code sample #1 but using a DependsOn for all implementations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes Indeed

```
container.Register( 
    Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<IUserMenuDao>() 
         .BasedOn<IDataAccess>()
         .WithService.FromInterface() 
         .Configure(c => c.DependsOn(new {strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABC123"].ConnectionString}))
    );
```

Comment: Greate! So many years have gone since 2012, but still very helpful - thanks a lot!